# Query in Google without using its API

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to query some text in google and retrieve the result count, for example if I search for "C#" I get `About 101,000,000 results (0.40 seconds)`, I want to get that number to make a ranking of all the queries that are going to be passed to the program. 
The code above is what I've done so far, but it isn't working, it is just retrieving google home page.

```
    private string _address = "https://www.google.com/?gl=us&hl=en&gws_rd=cr&pws=0#gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&q=";
    public void ProcessQuery(Query query)
    {
        string uri = _address + query.QueryText;
        string tag = "<div id=\"resultStats\">";
        int index;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader s = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        string result = s.ReadToEnd();
        index = result.IndexOf(tag) + tag.Length;
        result = result.Substring(index, 100);
        index = result.IndexOf("About ")+6;
        result = result.Substring(index);
        index = result.IndexOf(" ");
        result = result.Substring(0,index);
    }
```

`Query` is just a class that retrieves and formats the text that is passed to the program.

Edit: I also want to do it without using any external library.

Comment: it retrieves ONLY the home page because obviously the `QueryText` propery is coming in empty. Debug your program and you'll find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash mark (`#`) in `C#` has special meaning when used in a URL. You have to URL-encode it before adding it to the query string, e.g. using [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string uri = _address + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query.QueryText);
```

Comment: Sorry, not personal but how do you know `QueryText` hasn't been url-encoded already? Also, even if it's not...don't you think it'll show at least a results page for the keyword `C` instead of Google's home page?

Comment: @Leo Try to access https://www.google.com/?gl=us&hl=en&gws_rd=cr&pws=0#gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&q=C#

Comment: @Leo Compared to https://www.google.com/?gl=us&hl=en&gws_rd=cr&pws=0#gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&q=C%23

Comment: my bad...I think I need a coffee...upvoting now

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the encoding, but the response I'm obtaining from the request is the google homepage and not the desired search. I don't know why, because when I use Bing address it works very good.

Comment: @FabricioMonsalve Take a look at this: http://www.felling-software.com/2015/05/23/a-simple-google-search-client-in-csharp/

Comment: The HTML tag you're searching for does not appear in the page source at all, even when retrieved through the browser. I'm assuming that Google is dynamically loading this data through AJAX.

Comment: That article helped a lot! 
Now I have an idea about how to get the result I want, thank you very much :D

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Hi, The link you supplied is broken :-( Can you please write it again? it seems it helped the guy, and I would like to read it too.

Comment: @SItzik The Wayback Machine archived a copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20180204014744/http://www.felling-software.com/2015/05/23/a-simple-google-search-client-in-csharp/